# Could this HTML + CSS question have been saved by including an arbitrary code snippet?

Tags: discussion, closed-questions

I'm invested in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65291742/snake-like-border-animation) as I put some effort into an answer only to discover, upon posting, that the question had been closed.

Requirements to rectify the question are listed as:

1. including desired behaviour
2. and a specific problem/error
3. and the shortest code to reproduce the problem

I personally find the first two requirements are fulfilled:

1. The asker did a fine job of describing what they want
2. The problem is specific: use HTML + CSS to achieve the desired, well-defined result

The last requirement is not directly met as there is no code included. (It's worthwhile noting the question's *image* "reproduces" the problem very well without any need for *code*.)

I find it likely that the closers made their decision based on the simple absence of code. (Although they may have had other good reasons I haven't thought of, in which case my question here is less relevant!)

**Could this question have avoided closure if it included an arbitrary amount of code?** Imagine this snippet appeared in the question:

```
.snake-box {
  position: relative;
  border: 1px solid cyan;
  /* TODO: Spinning snake-like border */
}
```

This extremely simple code "reproduces" the problem - there is the container, but it's lacking the spinning snake-like border! This code, however, is so trivial that it is essentially noise, almost deserving to be edited out.

**More generally, is holding the requirement that some code must be present still applicable when dealing with HTML + CSS (and other UI) questions? Are we certain that images and explanatory text can never fill this same role?**

Comment: I think it would help to post a minimal reproducible example of HTML code that creates the image you have in your question.

Comment: That would undeniably be helpful! Although it carries the assumption that the asker has found a way to produce that image with css (they may have generated it with ms paint, for example!)

Comment: Presumably you should be able to create a blue frame, though!

Comment: Agreed, certainly! But I think code which merely applies a border is so trivial that it may *reduce* the "answerability" of the question - this is the conundrum I'm trying to get at with this question :)

Comment: I would argue that any code, as long as it's not completely unrelated, enhances the question.

Comment: I don't believe this meta question was asked in good faith and is actually seeking constructive discussion.

Comment: @HereticMonkey Why? :( If an aspect of the question indicates poor faith I'll happily edit on your advice...

Comment: The pejorative use of "arbitrary" and "rigid"; the assumption of how closers made their decision. It reads like a rant rather than an invitation to discuss.

Comment: The pejorative use of "arbitrary" is intentional to describe the actions of someone who wants to game the system and create an "unclosable" question lazily. My assumption is followed by an acknowledgement that I may be wrong. I've edited "rigid". If you smell any more poor faith please let me know!

Comment: Being punished for providing comprehensive answers is not uncommon. But I can't find some examples here on Meta right now.

Comment: Related (cross site): *[How can I avoid a question getting protected in middle of writing an answer?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/354447)*

Comment: Yikes that's a bunch of downvotes! Hopefully I'll eventually figure out how to post more in keeping with people's expectations on this forum

Comment: Besides quality, meta votes indicate agreement/disagreement.

Comment: @philipxy I don't see how one can agree/disagree with a *question*, apart from judging its quality...

Comment: I am just telling you how votes on posts are used on meta sites. Please google re voting on meta & read the [help]. By "agreement/disagreement" I include "yes/no" in response to a request or proposal.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The OP said:

> I've been trying to create a border animation

Then

> I also tried a few other ideas

and

> I've been trying to get this done for almost 2 days now and none of the solutions were working as hoped.

Well, a lot of tries and we see nothing in the question. The OP is required to show us what he did so we can help him fix his issues.

The banner on the top says:

> Edit the question to include desired behavior, a specific problem or error, **and the shortest code necessary to reproduce the problem**. This will help others answer the question.

It's clear that if the OP provided his code, it would be eaiser for us to help him instead of starting the whole work from scratch.

---

> Could this question have avoided closure if it included an arbitrary amount of code?

No, because we are not Robo-reviewers and we can identify what is relevant and what is not. You can make the question worse by doing this.

Comment: First time reading that question, but I've been arguing with myself that the question might be considered as "how-to" (which does not necessarily need code) instead of a "debugging problem" (which certainly needs code). But I guess that's a wording problem...

Comment: Thanks for the answer Temani! I'm wording myself carefully as a user above cast doubt on my intentions - to better understand I'd like to know: if the asker chose not to mention their previous attempts, and had included the trivial snippet from my answer, would the question still deserve to be closed? (And if so, why?) My overall interest is to understand if the presence of code is simply a formality that must be followed, even if the question is clear without such code.

Comment: @AndrewT. I myself considered the same (I didn't vote to close the question and only commented with some related links) but I can understand the reason of the closure and it's logical for me

Comment: @Gershom including trivial snippet simply to bypass the rules is a clear NO for me. We don't do blind review of question. A trivial/random code, an irrelevant code, a code you copied from another souce (with no reference) and 0 code are all equivalent to me and it's not a formality at all. We use that code to understand where the OP failed and give accurate answers.

Comment: @TemaniAfif I'd never call the reviewers on this site "blind" - quite the opposite! Would it be right to say that even if a question provides a short bit of code, that code could still be considered insufficient, and the question would still be at risk of being closed due to a lack of debugging details?

Comment: @Gershom yes, if the code is not enough to show/reproduce any issue then it's insufficient and the question may be closed

Comment: @TemaniAfif One final question (sorry to pester): what if a user's best code effort is still very lacking? Would they simply not be "fit" enough to deserve to post their question on SO? (Not asking rhetorically, I think both yes and no are valid answers)

Comment: @Gershom it depends. Each question is judjed individually. Sometimes you don't need to show any code and the question is valid. Ex: https://stackoverflow.com/q/65191293/8620333 --> this question is about CSS properties and the OP made a clear description of what he did use trying to achieve the result and it's enough.

Comment: @TemaniAfif In that case I still don't exactly understand why the linked question was closed, but I have no experience reviewing, and I trust a consensus of 3 reviewers (and commenters here) that there is *something* wrong with it. Anyways, thanks for the answers

Comment: @Gershom the question was closed because it asks for a *complex* thing and the OP said he tried to achieve it and failed. The issue here is that we don't see the attempt in order to understand what is the issue and fix it. I personnally would have closed the question as *too broad* because it's not clear to me what should be the behavior. You will see that I already commented that question with some solution and didn't add an answer because I was not sure what kind of animation need to be done.